# Trigger a workflow using another workflow

Tags: workflow, field-update, time-dependent-workflow

I am currently using two workflows to check if a record has been updated or not on a daily basis. The first workflow has the following logic :

**(If RecordName equals 'RECORDNAME' , AND If Status equals Completed ---> Send Email to User AND Update Status_Check (checkbox) field to TRUE )** with time trigger of one hour.

The second workflow has the Logic

**If Status_Check equals TRUE ---> Update Status_Check (checkbox) field to False** with time trigger of one hour.

In both the workflow's field updates the Re-evaluate workflow rules after field change is activated. The problem now is when a record is created the email is sent and the Status_Check is updated to TRUE. Later the second workflow is triggered and the Status_Check is updated to false. But after the field is updated by the second workflow the first workflow is not triggered again. Can anyone please tell me what the problem here is?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a bug, you should open a case with support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have selected **'created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria'** as evaluation criteria.
Since your RecordName **still equals 'RECORDNAME'** and the Status **still equals 'Completed'**, the first workflow doesn't fire again.

Including in your first workflow rule criteria that Status_Check must equal False should do the trick.